# adding customized parameters to pass as json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, titanium, parameter-passing, titanium-mobile

I am sending the parameters using post method to my rails server using this code in titanium-

```
if (email.value != '' && password.value != '')
{
    loginReq.open("POST","http://192.168.0.187:3000/users/sign_in");
    var params = {
        email: email.value,
        password: password.value
    };
    loginReq.send(params);
}
```

On rails server side I am getting this output on console -

```
Parameters: {"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "email"=>"abcdefgh@gmail.com"}
```

But I need the output like this -

```
Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"abcdefgh@gmail.com", "password"=>
FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign in"}
```

How to add `user` in parameters as above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't necessarily see the value in it, but you could change this:

```
var params = {
    email: email.value,
    password: password.value
};
```

to this:

```
var params = {
    user: {
        email: email.value,
        password: password.value
    },
    commit: "Sign In"
};
```

That would give you the output you're looking for.

Comment: But then now I am getting parameters like this:                  Parameters: {"user"=>"{password=96e79218965eb72c92a549dd5a330112, email=123saurabhjain@gmail.com}"}

Comment: Is it not what you asked to get as params?

Comment: this is different from what I wrote:    "password"=>[FILTERED]" is now changed to password=96e79218965eb72c92a549dd5a330112 and same is for email.

Comment: hmm... well I can't speak for the Appcelerator framework and how it handles JSON, but I can tell you that the JSON I provided is correct. The fact that the output is not what you expect might be a quirk of the framework, so you might need to play with the format of the JSON that you pass to it. For instance, try wrapping the parameters as an array rather than an object.